# How to calculate reward payout for delegators?

Tags: baker, delegating

I am planning on setting up a small staking service and accept delegations. My question is what is the best way to get the reward to be paid out to each of my delegators. Is there an optimal method to calculate this? Do I have to take periodic snapshots myself and store in a DB?

Ideally I would like to calculate this amount and perform this payout myself after I receive the reward without using something like TAPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [TRD](https://github.com/tezos-reward-distributor-organization/tezos-reward-distributor). It's extremely easy to use/setup. You can run it in "calculation only" mode and it will create a CSV report of how much to pay your delegates. But why not just let the script do that for you anyways? TRD is 100% automated/hands-free.

Comment: Thanks, looks good

Comment: @Santiago Please mark as answered

Comment: By calculation only mode you meant --dry-run correct? Or is there any other method in TRD? Thanks

Comment: Yes, use `-D` for dry-run mode.